# Multiple tabs with materialize next (V1)?

Tags: materialize, angular5

I cannot use multiple tabs in the same page while using materialize v1 and angular.

This is my app.component.ts:

`

```
/* import { Component } from '@angular/core'; */
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import 'materialize-css';
declare var M: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'app';

  ngOnInit() {
    const instanceSidenav = new M.Sidenav(document.querySelector('.sidenav'));
    const instanceTab = new M.Tabs(document.querySelector('.tabs'));
  }
}
```

`

And the sidenav menu works and even the first tab in the page works, but the second one doesnt' work. I turned the first to be the second and the same ocurs with the new second tabs.

What can I do without jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make it work: Instead of initialize the tabs in the official documentation way that uses a class selector inside a `document.querySelector('.tabs')` , I used ids selectors in this way `document.querySelector('#tab1')`.

This worked for me until I think the problem needs a better approach.